# SVG: float a shape over another shape?

Tags: html, svg

I have two circle shapes I'm working with in HTML markup. Is it possible to position one atop another, setting order w/ a z-index type property? Currently my shapes render next to each other:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

thanks

Comment: It'd most likely be better to just have both shapes in the same <svg> fragment, is it a requirement that they be separate fragments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use standard CSS positioning, e.g.

```
svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Adjust as you see fit.

Comment: thanks -- standard CSS position did the trick. didn't realize SVG elements were just like normal elements in this regard. great.

Answer (score 1):

using the above suggestions to use normal CSS positioning, this is what i did to obtain relative layer positioning:

```
#svgHolder {
    position:relative
}
.svgCircle2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:15px;
}


<div id="svgHolder">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" />
    </svg>

    <svg class="svgCircle2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="35" cy="35" r="35" fill="yellow" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

USE this FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/4wpw6add/8/

```
<svg class="bottom"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" />
    </svg>

    <svg class="top" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="yellow" />
    </svg>


.bottom{
    margin:0;
}

.top{
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
top: 34px;
left: 30px;
text-align:center;
}
```